# How to make tabbed labels responsive?

Tags: css, responsive

I have a tabbed feature on my site, and it is responsive, except for the labels.  I am not sure what to add to my style sheet to get the labels to wrap properly. Right now, when I reduced the size of the div, the labels spill out.

Here is a fiddle of what I have, everything I have tried so far has not worked, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

```
<https://jsfiddle.net/v9eu9gsL/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that technically speaking, if there was a front-end Bible, the responsiveness commandment would sound something like

> *Thine content shall be visible and accessible on all devices.*

However, having a design background, I have a tendency to read it as

> *Thine content shall work and not look broken on any device.*

Now, no matter how I look at this, it looks broken to me, although it's technically responsive:

[image]

So... this is how I'd fix it:

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .tabs {
    display: flex;
  }
  .tabs  li {
    max-width: 33.33%;
    flex: 1 1 33.33%;
  }
  .tabs li a {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 419px) {

  .tabs {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .tabs li {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .tabs li a {
    white-space: normal;
  }
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/2k0jovwu/)

Comment: I was working on fixing the length problem, I agree, that did make it look "broken" although it wasn't - thank you so much for taking the time to write this out - this is very helpful and it looks great!

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w0x7ju9y/

Comment: Thank you so much!